# C: How do I differentiate between an array of pointers and a pointer to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Say I have the following code:

```
// x = whatever number

int *arr_of_ptr[x];
int （*ptr_to_arr)[x]

int **p1 = arr_of_ptr;
int **p2 = ptr_to_arr;
```

My understanding of `arr_of_ptr` is that "dereferencing an element of arr_of_ptr results in an int" - therefore the elements of `arr_of_ptr` are *pointers to integers*. On the other hand, dereferencing `ptr_to_arr` results in an array that I can then nab integers from, hence `ptr_to_arr` *points to an array*.

I also have a rough understanding that arrays themselves are pointers, and that `arr[p]` evaluates to `(arr + p * sizeof(data_type_of_arr))` where the name `arr` decays to the pointer to the first element of `arr`.

So that's all well and good, but is there any way for me to tell whether `p1` and `p2` are `pointers to arrays` or `arrays of pointers` without prior information?

My confusion mostly stems from the fact that (I think) we can evaluate `int **p` two ways:

1. `*(p + n * size)` is what's giving me an int
2. `(*p + n * size)` is what's giving me an int

In hindsight this question might be poorly worded because I'm confusing myself a bit just looking back on it, but I really don't know how to articulate myself better. Sorry.

Comment: "any way for me to tell whether p1 and p2 are pointers to arrays or arrays of pointers without prior information?" --> `_Generic` may help.

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are both pointer to pointer . The initialization of p2 is a constraint violation and the compiler must generate a diagnostic (which you should not ignore)

Comment: For `p1` (which is correct), read [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to understand why. For `p2` you have a pointer to array of `[x]` elements, When you dereference `p2` what do you get? (an `array[x]` *not* a pointer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but, if I dereference `ptr_to_arr` and get a `something[x]`, doesn't `something` evaluate to a pointer?

Comment: No. Why? You have a *Pointer to an Array*. When you dereference a pointer, you reference the object stored at that location. What is stored at the address held by a *Pointer to an Array*? (hint: an Array `:)` Why this matters is with an *array of pointers* you have a collection of pointers, and `array + 1` advances `sizeof (a_pointer)` to the next pointer. When you have a *pointer to array* `ptr_to_arr + 1` advances `sizeof(arr[x])` to the next array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hmm, thanks for the response. I think I understand what you are saying, but my confusion stems from this:


`int arr[]; // here arr evaluates to a pointer int (*arr_ptr)[]; int arr2[] = *arr_ptr; // arr2 should evaluate to another pointer`

if arr2 = *arr_ptr and arr2 evaluates to a pointer, shouldn't *arr_ptr also evaluate to a pointer?

Comment: Start with a plain old array `int arr[3]`; On access (subject to the 4 exceptions [3 in C18 - `_Alignof` has been removed]) an *array* is converted to a pointer to the first element (`int` here). So `int *b = arr;` initializes `b` with the address of (e.g. to point to) the first element of `arr`. `*arr_ptr` is not a valid initializer (it's not a brace enclosed list). So int `arr2[] = *arr_ptr;` generates the  error `"invalid initializer"`.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that this is legal:

```
int **p1 = arr_of_ptr;
```

While this is not:

```
int **p2 = ptr_to_arr;
```

Because `arr_of_ptr` is an array, it can (in most contexts) *decay* to a pointer to its first element.  So because the elements of `arr_of_ptr` are of type `int *`, a pointer to an element has type `int **` so you can assign it to `p1`.

`ptr_to_arr` however is not an array but a pointer, so there's no decaying happening.  You're attempting to assign an expression of type `int (*)[x]` to an expression of type `int **`.  Those types are incompatible, and if you attempt to use `p2` you won't get what you expect.

Comment: Edit but 5 minutes are past: still a bit confused on second thought; what exactly is wrong with `int (*)[x]`? With `*arr[]`, `arr` decays to a pointer so it's `**`, but with `(*arr)[]` isn't `arr` itself a pointer, which gives an array "name" that also decays to a pointer?


Maybe that was badly worded. A better phrasing might be: if `(*arr)` gives me a pointer to the first element of an array, surely `arr` is a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: `*arr` is not a pointer.  It is an array of type `int [x]`.  Just because arrays can decay into pointers doesn't mean they're the same thing.

Comment: Shoot, I'm really sorry to dig this up again but I think I finally understand what you mean; an array of pointers is immediately an array that can decay to a pointer, so it can be interpreted as a pointer to a pointer, but a pointer to an array is immediately a pointer, so the array "behind" the pointer is stuck as an array and can't decay, right? However, if I had type `int (*)[x]` and dereferenced it, then I would get an array that could decay. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

First,

> I also have a rough understanding that arrays themselves are pointers, and that arr[p] evaluates to (arr + p * sizeof(data_type_of_arr)) where the name arr decays to the pointer to the first element of arr.

This isn't strictly correct.  Arrays are not pointers. Under most circumstances, *expressions* of array type will be converted ("decay") to expressions of pointer type and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  That pointer value is computed as necessary and isn't stored anywhere.

Exceptions to the decay rule occur when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

Having said all that, `ptr_to_arr` has *pointer* type, not array type - it will not "decay" to `int **`.

Given the declaration

```
T arr[N];
```

the following are true:

```
 Expression        Type            Decays to            Equivalent expression
 ----------        ----            ---------            ---------------------
        arr        T [N]           T *                  &arr[0]
       *arr        T               n/a                  arr[0]
     arr[i]        T               n/a                  n/a
       &arr        T (*)[N]        n/a                  n/a
```

The expressions `arr`, `&arr[0]`, and `&arr` all yield the same value (modulo any differences in representation between types).  `arr` and `&arr[0]` have the same type, "pointer to `T`" (`T *`), while `&arr` has type "pointer to N-element array of `T`" (`T (*)[N]`).

If you replace `T` with pointer type `P *`, such that the declaration is now

```
P *arr[N];
```

you get the following:

```
 Expression        Type            Decays to            Equivalent expression
 ----------        ----            ---------            ---------------------
        arr        P *[N]          P **                 &arr[0]
       *arr        P *             n/a                  arr[0]
     arr[i]        P *             n/a                  n/a
       &arr        P *(*)[N]       n/a                  n/a
```

So given your declarations, it would be more correct to write something like this:

```
int arr[x];
int *p1 = arr;         // the expression arr "decays" to int *

int *arr_of_ptr[x];
int **p2 = arr_of_ptr; // the expression arr_of_ptr "decays" to int **

/**
 * In the following declarations, the array expressions are operands
 * of the unary & operator, so the decay rule doesn't apply.
 */
int (*ptr_to_arr)[x] = &arr;
int *(*ptr_to_arr_of_ptr)[x] = &arr_of_ptr;
```

Again, `ptr_to_arr` and `ptr_to_arr_of_ptr` are *pointers*, not arrays, and do not decay to a different pointer type.

**EDIT**

From the comments:

> Can I just hand-wavily explain it as： an array of pointers has a name that can decay to a pointer,

Yeah, -ish, just be aware that it is hand-wavey and not really accurate (which is shown by example below).  If you are a first-year student, your institution isn't doing you any favors by making you deal with C this early.  While it is the substrate upon which most of the modern computing ecosystem is built, it is an *awful* teaching language.  *Awful*.  Yes, it's a small language, but aspects of it are deeply unintuitive and confusing, and the interplay between arrays and pointers is one of those aspects.

> an array of pointers has a name that can decay to a pointer, but a pointer to an array, even when dereferenced, does not give a give me something that decays to a pointer?

Actually...

If `ptr_to_arr` has type `int (*)[x]`, then the expression `*ptr_to_arr` would have type `int [x]`, which *would* decay to `int *`.  The expression `*ptr_to_arr_of_ptr` would have type `int *[x]`, which would decay to `int **`.  This is why I keep using the term "*expression* of array type" when talking about the decay rule, rather than just the name of the array.

Something I have left out of my explanations until now - *why* do array expressions decay to pointers?  What's the reason for this incredibly confusing behavior?

C didn't spring fully-formed from the brain of Dennis Ritchie - it was derived from an earlier language named B (which was derived from BCPL, which was derived from CPL, etc.)<sup>1</sup>.  B was a "typeless" language, where data was simply a sequence of words or "cells".  Memory was modeled as a linear array of "cells".  When you declared an N-element array in B, such as

```
auto arr[N];
```

the compiler would set aside all the cells necessary for the array elements, *plus* an extra cell that would store the numerical offset (basically, a pointer) to the first element of the array, and that cell would be bound to the variable `arr`:

```
     +---+
arr: | +-+-----------+
     +---+           |
      ...            |
     +---+           |
     |   | arr[0] <--+
     +---+
     |   | arr[1]
     +---+
      ...
     +---+
     |   | arr[N-1]
     +---+
```

To index into the array, you'd offset `i` cells from the location stored in `arr` and dereference the result.  IOW, `a[i]` was exactly equivalent to `*(a + i)`.

When Ritchie was developing the C language, he wanted to keep B's array semantics (`a[i]` is still exactly equivalent to `*(a + i)`), but for various reasons he didn't want to store that pointer to the first element.  So, he got rid of it entirely.  Now, when you declare an array in C, such as

```
int arr[N];
```

the only storage set aside is for the array elements themselves:

```
+---+
|   | arr[0]
+---+
|   | arr[1]
+---+
 ... 
+---+ 
|   | arr[N-1]
+---+
```

There is no separate object `arr` which stores a pointer to the first element (which is part of why array expressions cannot be the target of an assignment - there's nothing to assign *to*).  Instead, that pointer value is computed as necessary when you need to subscript into the array.

This same principal holds for multi-dimensional arrays as well.  Assume the following:

```
int a[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

What you get in memory is the following:

```
   Viewed as int             Viewed as int [2]
   +---+                     +---+
a: | 1 | a[0][0]           a:| 1 | a[0]
   +---+                     + - +
   | 2 | a[0][1]             | 2 |
   +---+                     +---+
   | 3 | a[1][0]             | 3 | a[1]
   +---+                     + - +
   | 4 | a[1][1]             | 4 |
   +---+                     +---+
```

On the left we view it as a sequence of `int`, while on the right we view it as a sequence of `int [2]`.

Each `a[i]` has type `int [2]`, which decays to `int *`.  The expression `a` itself decays from type `int [2][2]` to `int (*)[2]` (**not** `int **`).

The expression `a[i][j]` is exactly equivalent to `*(a[i] + j)`, which is equivalent to `*( *(a + i) + j )`.

---

1. As detailed in [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! But, as a first year student, this is just getting my mind into an awful twist. I sort of understand what you're saying, but I look away for five seconds and suddenly I'm confused again... Can I just hand-wavily explain it as： an array of pointers has a name that can decay to a pointer, but a pointer to an array, even when dereferenced, does not give a give me something that decays to a pointer? (basically, what I'm wondering is whether `*&arr` would give me back `arr` that can decay.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    int *p1 = &arr[0];
    int *p2 = &arr[1];
    int *p3 = &arr[2];
    int* arr2[3];
    arr2[0] = p1;
    arr2[1] = p2;
    arr2[2] = p3;
    int *p4 = &arr;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(p4));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr2));
    printf("%d\n", *p4);  // not **p4
    printf("%d\n", **arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code *arr* is a normal integer array with 3 elements. 
*p1*, *p2*, and *p3* are normal pointers to these elements. 
**arr2** is an **array of pointers** storing *p1*, *p2*, and *p3*.
**p4** is a **pointer to array** pointing to array *arr*

According to your question, you need to differentiate between *p4* and *arr2*
Since, *p4* is a pointer, its size is fixed (8 bytes) while size of *arr2* vaires on how many elements it contains (8x3=24).
Also, to print value contained in p4 use use single dereferencing (*p4) not **p4 (illegal), while to print value contained in arr2 use use double dereferencing (**arr2).
The output of above code is :

```
8
24
1
1
```

Comment: "_According to your question, you need to differentiate between p4 and arr2_". No, OP wants to differentiate b/w `p1` & `p2` without any prior information that what object they point to?